# How I can prevent hiding keyboard with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, keyboard, tpkeyboardavoiding

I want to avoid hiding keyboard when user even submit the form(like whatsapp or facebook).I use this code but it doesn't work.

```
$(document).on("click touchstart touchend",".mes-send-text",function(){
$(".mes-tbox").focus();
})
//.mes-send-text is button
//.mes-tbox is textarea
```

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the `.focus()` call inside a `setTimeout()`?  I've noticed that I have to do that (with some non-zero delay) or the textbox doesn't actually get focused properly.

Comment: I also used `.blur()` it works but has bug

Comment: Have you *tried* `setTimeout()`?

Comment: How can I use it? can you give sample?

Comment: [How to use setTimeout()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp). Replace `$(".mes-tbox").focus();` with `setTimeout(function(){$(".mes-tbox").focus();},100);`

Comment: Are you sure the function is being called at all?  Insert a `console.log("some message")` statement.  There are a number of things that could be going wrong and you have to learn how to debug.

Comment: I was sure.It works as a function,but doesn't do smth.

Comment: I need that emergency,please help me to figure out that

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, I was [unconscious and hallucinating](http://xkcd.com/203/).  SO isn't here to give you immediate results and write your code for you.  Try giving the textbox an ID rather than a straight class, you may also wish to create a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) that other people can poke at to try and figure out why your code isn't doing what you expect.  There's only so much I can do through comments.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/g7rfnnuL/1/   that's the sample.Can you check and write some codes

Comment: Your fiddle works for me.  I click the button and the textbox remains highlighted.  I even checked on my Android tablet (in Chrome) and the keyboard remained active.  Even when I scrolled the page (keyboard hides) and clicked send the textbox was immediately highlighted and the keyboard returned.  What browser are you using?

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have an Apple product available to test with.